# Rails 3 ActionMailer attachments incorrectly shown inline by Yahoo! Mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-3, yahoo, icalendar

I am using ri_cal gem to generate ics file.

In my mailer:--

```
def appointment_book(appointment,recipient,appointment_with)
  event = RiCal.Event do
    description "MA-6 First US Manned Spaceflight"
    dtstart     DateTime.parse(appointment.slot.date_on.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").to_s + " " + appointment.slot.start_time.strftime("%I.%M %p").to_s)
    dtend       DateTime.parse(appointment.slot.date_on.strftime("%m/%d/%Y").to_s + " " + appointment.slot.end_time.strftime("%I.%M %p").to_s)
    add_attendee appointment_with.full_name
    alarm do
      description "Segment 51"
    end
  end
  attachments['event.ics'] = { 
   :mime_type => 'text/calendar', 
   :content => event.export 
   }

  @recipient = recipient
  @appointment = appointment
  mail(:to => recipient.email, :subject => "Appointment book")
end
```

in appintment_book.text.erb file

```
  (some simple variable values or plain text.)
```

Issue is (In Yahoo, specifically newer version. I am adding screenshots in edit part):--

attachment is there is mail, but apart from gmail content of the mail is having some vcard and other content. If i remove ics_generation code then its gone. Please check screenshots

In gmail it looks like (Also working on hotmail):--

[image: gmaill look]

**EDIT**

**Working in yahoo Classic.**

### [image: Working in yahoo classic]

**Not working in New yahoo:--**

[image]

Comment: In my testing this problem wasn't limited to ICS files; VCF and plain text files from Rails caused the same problem in Yahoo! Mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit unsure what you're showing and asking. Assuming the first screenshot is an unnamed mail client incorrectly showing the icalendar data instead of having it as an attachment and you're wanting to fix that, then I'd suggest you specify the mime type, as in

```
 attachments['event.ics'] = { 
   :mime_type => 'text/calendar', 
   :content => event.export 
 }
```

I can't say if this will help that mail client and/or calendar data, but it does the trick for vCard attachments in most clients, as in:

```
 attachments['card.vcs'] = { 
   :mime_type => 'text/x-vcard', 
   :content => person.to_vcf 
 }
```

---

Thanks for the clarification, unfortunately for *that question* I've no answer better than "tell Yahoo," which is no help.

I sent attachments to Yahoo mail from a few different sources and I tried different content types, transfer encodings (e.g., Base64), different kinds of attachments, etc. The only constant I can find between those that Yahoo shows properly and those it fails on is that the successes do **not** use parameter folding, e.g.,

**Success**

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="event.ics"
```

**Fail**

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="event.ics"
```

This (correct) folding appears to be hardwired into the [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) that Rails uses and I didn't try another way of truly isolating it; I have to say I'd be surprised if that were really the problem.

Regardless, Yahoo is rendering non-inline attachments as inline, so if this is a significant problem for your customer base, I'd take it up with Yahoo directly; maybe they'll fix it or offer you a more concrete statement about what triggers it so you can work around it. For what it's worth, Yahoo does allow the user to access the attachment correctly as it should with Content-Disposition of "attachment"; it's just *also* showing it as if the Disposition where "inline."

By the way, this problem affects my apps as well, so I'll keep thinking about things for us to try.

Comment: Also please check it again. Updated the question.

Comment: @piemesons: I updated my answer, or rather, indicated I've no proper answer for the clarified question.

Comment: :-(.. anyways thanks a lot. 50+ for u :-) If  you encounter with any solution. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This issue in only related to Yahoo! Mail. What a shame that Yahoo! Mail does not manage iCalendar events in Yahoo! Calendar yet, in 2011!

At least events are now provided as ICS attachments in "new" Yahoo! Mail and you can manage invitations manually. Maybe Yahoo! Classic did in the past. I will check and consider to revert possibly.

This is the only solution for people keeping on using Yahoo! Webmail service. Of course having a Yahoo! Mail account managed by a POP3 email client does manage iCalendars events properly: any attached ICS file shows up as a meeting invitation you can manage though your email client as usual.

Have a look here, at Yahoo! Developer Network : http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Problem-opening-ICS-files-from-Yahoo/1299668671000-24ed7a59-019f-3f1b-b596-70ab34db783c

Hope it helps,so late.